# Why Room's @Database gets entities as arrayOf in Kotlin, while Java does not take array?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

When I define Room's database with `@Database` in **Java**:

```
@Database(entities = {JustSomeEntity.class}, version = 1)
```

When I define Room's database with `@Database` in **Kotlin**:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(JustSomeEntity::class), version = 1)
```

Please note the **`arrayOf`** in Kotlin version.

See [official docs for reference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) - you can toggle Java/Kotlin there and see.

Is this some kind of Java / Kotlin / annotations quirk? Why is that? Where it comes from?

Comment: `{...}` is a shortcut syntax for creating an array in java, through not available in kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java curly braces define an array of values. See the docs:

```
Alternatively, you can use the shortcut syntax to create and initialize an array:

int[] anArray = { 
   100, 200, 300,
   400, 500, 600, 
   700, 800, 900, 1000
};
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html